# Не подключается страница ошибки(Apache2 ошибка HTTP 500)

Tags: http, apache2

Я в .httaccess файле прописал код для загрузки моей ошибки:

```
        ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?id=500
```

Но она не срабатывает (Я пропустил ; в PHP)
Хотя с другими ошибками все нормально

Добавлю код .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?id=500
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php?id=400
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php?id=401
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php?id=403
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?id=404
<Files "cookies.js">
<RequireAll>
Require all denied
</RequireAll>
</Files>
<Files "footer.php">
<RequireAll>
Require all denied
</RequireAll>
</Files>
<Files "header.php">
<RequireAll>
Require all denied
</RequireAll>
</Files>
<Files "db.php">
<RequireAll>
Require all denied
</RequireAll>
</Files>
<Files ".htaccess">
<RequireAll>
Require all denied
</RequireAll>
</Files>
```